# QTableView/QAbstractTableModel emit dataChanged()? where to connect

Tags: c++, qt

I have a `QTableView` and I have set as its model a class inherited from `QAbstractTableModel`. I have implemented the proper `rowCount()`, `columnCount()`, `data()` virtual methods that are need for a proper `TableModel`.

So my question is this. When the data in the model changes how can I tell the `QTableView` to update itself?

I looking through documentation is found that i should emit the signal `dataChanged()`... but i dont see what slot on the table view i should connect this to. I dont even see a slot on tableview that has the same parameters..

Here is the method that i emit data changed in:

```
void signalTapSignalAggregator::updateFinished(){
     QModelIndex topLeft = index(0, 0);
     QModelIndex bottomRight = index(numberOfRow, listOfSignals.size());
     beginResetModel();
     //emit  layoutAboutToBeChanged();
     emit layoutChanged();
     emit dataChanged(topLeft,bottomRight);
}
```

now after I emit `layoutChanged()` it seems that the tableview update the number of columns that are needed but there is no data in them.

i have set a break point on `data()` method of the model in hopes that I will see the `QTableView` attempt to read the new data but it never fires after I call `dataChanged()`

So how do I connect the `dataChanged()` signal to the `QTableView`?

Comment: the function you pasted is really messed up. You call `beginResetModel` without `endResetModel` and you don't seem to change any data structure there, then you emit `layoutChanged()` and `dataChanged()`. This is of course not the way these functions were designed to be used. I recommend you to read [Address Book Example](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtwidgets-itemviews-addressbook-example.html) and see how they subclass `QAbstractTableModel` in `TableModel` class.

Comment: yes that function is really messed up.. i was desperately trying anything i could to get the table to update. I will take your recamendation and read the Address Book Example. I did notice they are emitting dataChanged as well but i dont see them explicitly connecting this signal to a tableview... is the fact that the table set this as its model sufficient for this signal to be connected to some slot inside the tableview class??? i think that is my sticking point. thanks for the reply.

Comment: You don't have to connect those signals. Qt automatically sets up needed connections between the model and the view. I think that you should delete this question since it has no benefit for others, Just read the example, and if you have problems, please ask a clearer and a more accurate question.